# Python Script to compare du and df console outputs

Tags: python, linux, command-line-interface, mount, linux-disk-free

As part of a larger project, I'm currently writing a python script that runs Linux commands in a vApp.

I'm currently facing an issue where after working with a mounted iso, it may or may not unmount as expected.

To check the mount status, I want to run the `df -hk /directory` and `du -sch /directory` commands respectively, and compare the outputs.

If the iso is not unmounted, the result for the **df** command should return a larger value than the **du** command as the **df** command includes the mount size in the result, while **du** does not.

I'm just wondering how can i compare these values or if there is a better way for me to run this check in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use `/proc/mounts` ?
First column is you blockdevice, second is the mountpoint.
If you mountpoint is not in /proc/mounts you have nothing mounted here.